# dotcloud supervisord.conf file environment specification

Tags: dotcloud

http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/daemons/ states:

```
Configuring The Environment
You can easily modify the environment of execution of your daemon with the “directory” and “environment” directives to change the directory where the command is executed and to define additional environment variable. For example:

[program:daemonname]
command = php my_daemon.php
directory = /home/dotcloud/current/
environment = QUEUE=*, VERBOSE=TRUE
```

However, I'm finding my PYTHONPATH environment variable is not being set:

dotcloud.yml:

```
www:
  type: python
db:
  type: postgresql
worker:
  type: python-worker
```

supervisord.conf:

```
[program:apnsd]
command=/home/dotcloud/current/printenv.py
environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/dotcloud/current/apnsd/
```

printenv.py

```
#! /home/dotcloud/env/bin/python
import os
print "ENVIRONMENT"
print os.environ
```

the logs:

```
    ENVIRONMENT
    {'SUPERVISOR_ENABLED': '1', 'SUPERVISOR_SERVER_URL': 'unix:///var/dotcloud/super
    visor.sock', 'VERBOSE': 'no', 'UPSTART_INSTANCE': '', 'PYTHONPATH': '/', 'PREVLE
    VEL': 'N', 'UPSTART_EVENTS': 'runlevel', '/': '/', 'SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME': 'a
    pnsd', 'UPSTART_JOB': 'rc', 'PWD': '/', 'SUPERVISOR_GROUP_NAME': 'apnsd', 'RUNLE
    VEL': '2', 'PATH': '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    ', 'runlevel': '2', 'previous': 'N'}
```

Do not show a modified python variable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in Supervisor; some variables (like those containing a `/`) have to be quoted.

In that case, you need:

```
[program:apnsd]
command=/home/dotcloud/current/printenv.py
environment= PYTHONPATH="/home/dotcloud/current/apnsd/"
```

(The space in `= PYTHONPATH` is not mandatory, it's just to make the file slightly more readable; the quotes around the value of `PYTHONPATH` are, however, required!)

I will update dotCloud's documentation to mention this issue.

Comment: Thanks - I also just found that if you quote the directory variable, then Supervisor will exit with a ENOENT error: couldn't chdir to "/home/dotcloud/current/apnsd": ENOENT. So this may be related as well. Now having a different problem, but that's a topic for another post.